# Dynamically assigned value in dropdown always displaying the default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, drop-down-menu

The drop-down value is getting selected and I can see the value being highlighted in the drop-down but the display is always showing the first value of the drop-down. I am dynamically selecting the drop-down value in the java script depending on the value returned from other fields. The desktop version works fine but having problem with the mobile version and found that we are using jquery mobile version which could be the cause for this. Any help on how to overcome this.

Have already used the following

```
document.getElementById(ID).value = value;
```

Have provided `selected=true`, used the text option as well.

If i write a automation script my tests are getting passed as the value is getting selected properly but is not getting displayed in the dropdown. If I manually select the values from the drop down I can see the selected value being displayed in the drop-down.

Comment: Plenty of detail but no source code to debug. If we have nothing to debug how do you expect people to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To correctly assign value to a select widget, you need to marked its option to be selected:

```
document.getElementById('ID').getElementsByTagName('option')[1].selected = 'selected'
```

Answer (score -2):

using the jquery text() method to assign the dynamic value to drop-down. use the below code

```
$("#dropDownID option:selected").text()
```